# Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Sms is not supported

Tags: android, sms

I created app, that gives possibility to send sms.

I use method for sending sms:

```
 smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(smsPhone, null, smsBodyParts, 
 sentPendingIntents, deliveredPendingIntents);
```

Also I have added permissions in Manifest and runtime permissions for higher OS versions. App works perfect but one device Samsung Galaxy A7 crashes. And in crashlytics I have the log:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Sms is not supported
   at android.telephony.SmsManager.getISmsServiceOrThrow(SmsManager.java:815)
   at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessageInternal(SmsManager.java:575)
   at android.telephony.SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(SmsManager.java:544)
   at com.companyname.ProcessSMSService$SMSSendThread.run(ProcessSMSService.java:479)
```

I didn't find something useful in google, referes to my crash. Please help me. Why this crash occured? How can I cover that? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using like this - `(ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider()`@mrNobody

Comment: @Dhanshri I don't use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that particular device had not sms feature.So you need to check whether the device supports sms feature or not.

Comment: OK, maybe someone run app on samsung emulator and it led to crash, thanks I'll add checking to my app.